# Preview missing lots of fonts that are shown in font book

Tags: macos, preview, font

Clean almost untouched install of macOS Catalina 10.15.2.

I haven't installed any fonts yet.

Font book shows me fonts for example PSL Ornanong Pro. This font doesn't show up in Preview.

I would like to use this font in Preview.

How can I use all fonts from Preview?

Comment: Ornamong is for Thai script.  Is that what you want to write?

Comment: In my experience Preview can only use a subset of the fonts provided with macos.

Answer (score 1):

PSL Ornanong Pro is 'available to download' in Catalina: it is not initially installed. Have you actually downloaded it?

Font Book will display the name dimmed slightly. You can download it by clicking on `Edit > Download`, or `Download` on a right-click context menu.

Comment: I see some greyed-out fonts in the list. PSL Ornanong Pro is not one of them.... Additionally, there is no "Download" option in the context menu or in the Edit menu