# How to use a downloaded font in preview

Tags: preview, font

I've just downloaded a new font from the web, and installed it into the Font Book application, where I can find it under all fonts.

[image]

Specifially, "Diary Of A Wimpy Kid Font" is the one I'm referring to. I want to use it when editing a PDF with the preview application, but it doesn't show up there. Have I just missed a step? How do I use a font from font book in preview?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a bug in some versions of Preview so that some third-party fonts do not appear in the Annotations font selection control.

[Preview missing lots of fonts that are shown in font book](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/381894/preview-missing-lots-of-fonts-that-are-shown-in-font-book)

Also, note that amateur fonts which may not have been created to professional standards have traditionally been responsible for a variety of problems.

The books of "Diary of a Wimpy Kid" use ***Coop Forged*** as their typeface.
https://houseind.com/hi/typography_of_coop

Answer (score 1):

On a system running macOS Ventura (13.3), I was also unable to use fonts in Preview.app that had recently been installed and were visible in Font Book.app, but noticed that some fonts I'd previously installed *were* available in Preview. Restarting both applications didn't cause them to show up in Preview.

However, I've confirmed that fonts available in Font Book that are in either `/Library/Fonts/` or `~/Library/Fonts/` *are* available in Preview after a reboot.

Comment: Thanks, it was the reboot that worked for me too.

Answer (score -2):

After you open your file with Preview, go to Tools Menu/Annotate/Text. Click on text a toolbar will appear above your image. At the right end of the toolbar is an icon for text. This icon is a capital A and if you click on the arrow it will open a pane where you can select font and size. The pulldown should show all the fonts available. See the image below.

[image]

And,

[image]

Select the pulldown next to the 'A' at the end of the annotation toolbar.

Comment: The trouble is that sometimes for some reason that pulldown next to the A does not even have all the fonts included with MacOS, much less those added by the user.